# How can I build a string for return from a PHP function in an efficient and maintainable way?

Tags: php, function, output-buffering

I'm looking into automatically formatting some text over and over again in a project in a way that lends itself towards functions. These functions will stick the text together and format it correctly, including sticking `<span>` tags around the code, etc.

Is the following code the correct way to do this, or is it wasteful of memory because I'm loading all the text into a variable? Is there a better way to do the following?

```
function presentName ( $title, $fname, $lname )
{
    $return  = '<span class="name">';
    $return .= $title . ' ';
    $return .= $fname . ' ';
    $return .= $lname . '</span>';
    return $return;
}
```

I'm not looking for an alternative to a function in this context.

I am looking for a "less messy" or "less wasteful" way to refactor the function, probably with a way of buffering the output before it's returned. Some of my functions do things like render form input elements and these can get a bit messy.

Comment: `return "<span class=\"name\">$title $fname $lname</span>"`

Comment: This is a bit vague but if you build your webpage in a tag-by-tag procedure (as the above), you have no other option than using the above. Otherwise, you can build your dynamic variables first ($title,$fname etc.), then pass them to a template file via an include() (which will be rendered to a var via output-buffer). I know of this because i am working on a CMS and built already a form plugin, which required far more than title and name for example. Less messy, more organized, but memory wasteful sure, depends on your code and content size.

Comment: I'm aware that I could return the whole thing in one go, that's not really helping. I might, for example, choose to not include the last name in the returned string under certain circumstances or add other logic to the function. In such a case I would need to build up the output block at a time. I was really looking for a generally better way to write this type of function, not looking for someone to rewrite the function for me.

Answer (score 0):

a short and not really pretty way to do this would be this:

```
<?php
function presentName($title, $fname, $lname){
    return '<span class="name">'.$title.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.'</span>';
}
?>
```

a dot connects to parts so this:

```
echo "hello"."dude";
```

would show "hellodude"

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `sprintf()` to achieve a similar goal. Consider this example:

```
function presentName($title, $fname, $lname) {
    return sprintf('<span name="name">%s %s %s</span>', $title, $fname, $lname);
}
```